# While loop doesn't execute statements at each iteration

Tags: c, while-loop, variable-assignment

I'm a beginner in the C language and encountering a problem with a big while loop. Basically I have 2 variable assignments inside the loop that don't get executed at each iteration for some reason, so the value of the variable remains constant. Other than that, everything works just fine.

EDIT: I get it now that the variables I set as double defaults to int in the play() function.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int play();

int main()
{
    double correct, attempts;
    char host[10], player[10];

    system("cls");

    printf("What's up strangers! Welcome to my game.\n");
    printf("Please CAREFULLY read all prompts from this point forward.\n");

    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    printf("First thigs first, HOST, what is your name? ");
    scanf("%s", host);

    system("cls");

    printf("Ok %s, what is the number you would like the player to guess? ", 
host);
    scanf("%d", &correct);
    printf("Then how many attempts would like them to have on guessing? ");
    scanf("%d", &attempts);
    printf("Thank you %s, now please leave room for our fearless player of 
the day.\n", host);

    system("pause");
    system("cls");

    printf("Mighty player, your fearless game host for today is %s. Please 
enter your name: ", host);
    scanf("%s", player);

    system("cls");

    printf("Alright %s! The rule is simple, you have %d attempts to guess 
%s's number.", player, attempts, host);
    printf("Any time you guess wrong, the game will tell you how far off your 
answer was.\n");
    printf("Your score will be displayed at he end of the game.\n");
    printf("Whenever you are ready... Good luck!");

    system("pause");
    return play(correct, attempts, host, player);
}

play(correct, attempts, host, player)
{
    double count = 1, pcent, pdiff, answer;
    char score[1], suffix[2];

    while (count < attempts)
    {
        pcent = 100*sqrt(pow((1-(count/attempts)), 2));
        if (pcent == 100)
        {
            strcpy(score, "S");
        }
        else if (pcent < 100 && pcent >= 90)
        {
            strcpy(score, "A");
        }
        else if (pcent < 90 && pcent >= 80)
        {
            strcpy(score, "B");
        }
        else if (pcent < 80 && pcent >= 70)
        {
            strcpy(score, "C");
        }
        else if (pcent < 70 && pcent >= 60)
        {
            strcpy(score, "D");
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(score, "F");
        }

        if (count == 1)
        {
            strcpy(suffix, "st");
        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            strcpy(suffix, "nd");
        }
        else if (count == 3)
        {
            strcpy(suffix, "st");
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(suffix, "th");
        }

        printf("%d", pcent);
        printf("%s, please enter your %d%s guess: ", player, count, suffix);
        scanf("%d", &answer);
        pdiff = 200*((answer-correct)/(answer+correct));
        printf("%f", pdiff);

        system("cls");

        if (answer == correct)
        {
            printf("That is correct %s! You got it on your %d%s try.\n", 
player, count, suffix);
            printf("Your score is %s.", score);
            system("pause");
            return main();
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Wrong answer %s! Your guess was %f percent off from the 
correct answer.\n", player, pdiff);
            printf("You have %d attempts remaining.\n", attempts-count);
            system("pause");
        }
        count ++;
    }
    printf("Sorry %s, but you have no more attempt remaining... Please play 
again later.\n", player);
    return main();
}
```

Comment: My crystal ball says remove the `';'` after `while (stuff);`... Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page soon and also visit the links describing [How to Ask a Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (MCVE). Providing the necessary details, including your MCVE, compiler warnings and associated errors, if any, will allow everyone here to help you with your question.

Comment: `char score[1], suffix[2];` are both 1-char too short to hold the string you copy. You must have `char score[2], suffix[3];` minimum. Suggest `char score[8], suffix[8];` for both, or just make `score` a `char` instead of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Without your full code it is impossible to be 100% sure I have covered everything, but I believe I have captured what is apparent:

- Your primary math issue appears to be related to integer-division that occurs in both `pcent = 100*sqrt(pow((1-(count/attempts)), 2));` and in `pdiff = 200*((answer-correct)/(answer+correct));`. If you need the fractional part in each division, cast the divisor (or dividend) to `(double)`.
- Your arrays are *too-short-by-one* to hold the strings you attempt to `strcpy()` to them. Suggest making `score` a `char` and using `suffix[8]`. (better to be 10,000 characters *too long* than one character *too short*).
- always provide the **type** for each variable in your parameter list.
- always provide a `break;` statement in each `switch()` case (though you have now edited an used `if .. else if .. else`). If you fail to `break;` fall-through to the next case occurs.
- Your function type is `int`, so when you `return`, you `return value;` where `value` is type `int`, not `main()`. You do not need to return the calling function because your `play()` function has already stored the `frame-pointer` for `main()` as part of the *function prologue* and knows where to return control when it is done.
- choose a meaningful return, e.g. `return 1;` on error and `return 0;` on success, C provides two macros for that `EXIT_FALURE` (`1`) and `EXIT_SUCCESS` ( `0`).
- Validate **Every** user-input by ***checking the return***.
- Validate **Every** conversion by ***checking the return***.
- use a reasonable sized buffer (character array), and take all user-input using `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` so what remains unread in `stdin` does not depend on the conversion specifier or whether a *matching failure* occurs.
- use `sscanf()` to obtain (parse) individual values from your buffer, just as you would use `scanf()` but providing your buffer as the first argument.
- you only need one call to `printf()` (or `puts()` or `fputs()`) to output a sequential block of text -- no matter how many lines it is.
- use `printf()` only if conversions are required, otherwise use `puts()` if you want a `'\n'` automatically appended, and `fputs()` if you need end-of-line control -- such as prompting for input.
- `"The expression of each case label shall be an integer constant expression..."` [C11 Standard - 6.8.4.2 The switch statement(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.4.2p3) Your use of the range expressions, e.g. `60 ... 69` are provided by non-standard compiler extension only.

There are probably more changes I have forgotten to mention. I suspect your `player` is actually `char*`, but it was defaulting to `int` in your question due to lack of type. So change the `%d` used below in the `printf()` format string to `%s` if so. I have included further comments in-line below:

**Updated Function**

```
#define MAXC 256        /* if you need a constant, #define one or more */

int play (int correct, int attempts, int host, int player)
{
    int count = 1, answer = 0;                          /* initialize variables */
    char buf[MAXC] = "", score = 0, suffix[8] = "";
    double pdiff = 0., pcent = 0.;

    while (count < attempts)
    {
        pcent = 100 * sqrt(pow((1-((double)count/attempts)), 2));
        switch ((int)pcent)
        {
            case 60 ... 69:
                score = 'D'; break;             /* you must break or fall-through occurs */
            case 70 ... 79:
                score = 'C'; break;
            case 80 ... 89:
                score = 'B'; break;
            case 90 ... 99:
                score = 'A'; break;
            case 100:
                score = 'F'; break;
            default:
                score = 'S'; break;
        }

        switch (count)
        {
            case 1:
                strcpy (suffix, "st"); break;   /* ditto */
            case 2:
                strcpy (suffix, "nd"); break;
            case 3:
                strcpy (suffix, "rd"); break;
            default:
                strcpy (suffix, "th"); break;
        }

        printf ("percent: %.2f\n", pcent);          /* left alone since it looks like debug */
        printf ("%d, please enter your %d%s guess: ", player, count, suffix);
        
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin)) {            /* read & VALIDATE all user-input */
            puts ("(user canceled)");
            return 1;
        }
        
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &answer) != 1) {     /* validate EVERY conversion */
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            return 1;
        }
        pdiff = 200 * ((double)(answer-correct) / (answer+correct));
        printf ("%f", pdiff);

        // system("cls");           /* not really needed, just scrolls lines up */

        if (answer == correct)
        {
            printf ("That is correct %d! You got it on your %d%s try.\nYour score is %c.",
                    player, count, suffix, score);
            // system("pause");
            fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin);       /* will do nicely instead of pause */
            return 1;                       /* just return */
        }
        else
        {
            printf ("Wrong answer %d! "
                    "Your guess was %.2f percent off from the correct answer.\n"
                    "You have %d attempts remaining.\n", player, pdiff, attempts-count);
            // system("pause");
            fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin);       /* will do nicely instead of pause */
        }
        count++;
    }
    printf ("Sorry %d, but you have no more attempt remaining... "
            "Please play again later.\n", player);

    return 0;     /*just return -- the function handles saving the callers */
}
```

This is my best guess at what you needed. Adjust the type for `player` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Well wismus2999,

I believe that if the variables are of the integer type, you may not be modifying them, an example would be:

```c
while (<condition>) {
   a = 2;
}
```

the code above is different from this:

```c
while (<condition>) {
   a++;
   // or a = a + 1;
}
```

As there is no code or photos to analyze it is difficult to give a
concrete answer.

Comment: I think I posted the code above, could you not see it? (I'll try to repost if not) and I do not really understand your answer, I declared the counting variable as int count = 1 before the loop then put a count++ at the end. Thanks in advance!